# How to read a big binary file in Java

Tags: java, file, memory, binary

I want to read a binary file in Java, which contains m datasets. I know that each dataset consists of 3 elements: a long number, a double number and a long number in that sequence. The datasets are repeated one after each other till the end of the file. Supposing that the number m of datasets is known, how can I read the file in Java without passing all the datasets to main memory, so as to be able to read large files as well, which do not "fit" in the main memory?

Comment: `java.io.FileInputStream` `java.io.DataInputStream` `readLong()` `readDouble()`

Comment: I would look at the Apache Commons FileUtils http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html. It is often better than the standard utilities

Comment: @peter.murray.rust - except that it doesn't have methods for dealing with binary files.

Comment: try java.util.Scanner

Comment: The most important is however how to avoid passing the whole file in main menory, that is the point of my question.

Comment: Which do you want, random-access or sequential-access?

Comment: @johnchen902: sequential-access is better for this task.

Answer (score 3):

If you want sequential access:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("input.bin"))
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    long l1 = dis.readLong();
    double d1 = dis.readDouble();
    long l2 = dis.readLong();
    /* do what you need */
}
dis.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "records" in your file have a fixed size, you can use `RandomAccessFile`, and particularly the `seek` method to move to the position you want to read from.  The API also provides methods for reading longs and doubles.

> The instruction I have is: "The datasets should not be all read in main memory". How can I tackle this?

Use `seek` to position the file and only read the datasets that need to be read.

Comment: The instruction I have is: "The datasets should not be all read in main memory". How can I tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

I used java.nio http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html which provides buffering as I needed some additional functions like setting the byte order as well.
In addition to johnchen902's solution you read the number of bytes in your buffer from the stream and put them into the buffer.